# How to store more model properties in SelectList

Tags: javascript, view, properties, store, selectlist

I have a class ParameterDetails which contains fields:

```
    public long? ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public long? ParameterID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Unit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public long? DataType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Now I make a SelectList based on List of the ParameterDetails class elements:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.ParameterDetails.ID, new SelectList(
    Model.ParameterDetailsList.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "Unit"), new
    {
        @class = "form-control unit-dropdown dropdown",
        id = String.Format("Unit{0}", Model.Parameter.ID),
        onchange = "changeValidation(this);"
    })
```

**And now the question:**
How to access other fields than ID and UNIT from javascript "changeValidation" function??? 
I need DataType property to change the html "data-val-regex" attribute when I choose new item from selectlist

Answer (score 0):

Solved it a little around, using AJAX. I call a method that gets data from controller and then sends it in Json object to view.